# Is this set of functions open with this norm?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I would like to know:

Given $E$ the set of functions $C^1$ in $[0,1]$, with the norm $\lVert h\lVert_E = max(\lVert h\lVert,\lVert h'\lVert)$, where $\lVert h\lVert = sup_{x\in[0,1]} | h(x) | $, is the set $E'$ of the functions with one and just one $0$ in $]0,1[$ open?

I tried to prove that its complement is closed, by limit of sequences of functions and the mean value theorem, but I did not succeed.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: check neighborhood of function $\left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2$.

Comment: thank you for the answer